# join two tables with max value

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Imagine I have 2 tables:

with:

```
JOBS
====
NAMEJOB
A
B
C
D
D
E
```

and

```
versions
========
NAMEJOB    CREATION_DATE       VERSION     CURR_VER
A          20180301            2            N
A          20180307            1            Y
B          20180302            3            N
B          20180304            2            N
C          20180308            1            Y
```

I woud like to have all creation date of max(version) of table JOBS:

```
RESULT:
NAMEJOB    CREATION_DATE       VERSION
A          20180301            2
B          20180302            3
```

I'm trying to join but not works (only shows me three lines).

```
select max(version) as maximo, curr_ver, creation_date, a.namejob  
from versions a, jobs b
where a.namejob=b.namejob
group by curr_ver,creation_date, a.namejob
having 
max(version) in (select max(version) as global_max from versions a, jobs b
where a.namejob=b.namejob);
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

HERE IS THE SOLUTION:

```
   SELECT A.NAMEJOB,CREATION_DATE,VERSION
FROM VERSIONS B
INNER JOIN ( SELECT  V.NAMEJOB ,MAX(VERSION) AS MAXIMO
             FROM VERSIONS V
             WHERE CURR_VER!='Y' GROUP BY V.NAMEJOB ) AS A
ON A.NAMEJOB = B.NAMEJOB and A.MAXIMO=B.version
```

FOR demo please follow the link:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6a2f6/5

Comment: Wooo what a complex query? Could you explain me something why I must make a lot of joins? Thanks!

Comment: Hey In subquery we don't need any join. So, I edited my answer, have a look at it and tell me if you feel any difficulty to understand.

Comment: At least reply if you found it useful or not.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version

```
select namejob, creation_date, max(version) 
from versions
group by namejob
```

and if you want to only include current_ver = 'N' (not sure I understand why)

```
select namejob, creation_date, max(version) 
from versions
where curr_ver = 'N'
group by namejob
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why do you want to join table `JOBS`. A query on  `versions` table only using `KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST )` should work, as it seems from your desired output .

```
SELECT NAMEJOB,
         MIN (CREATION_DATE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY VERSION DESC)
            AS CREATION_DATE,
         MAX (VERSION) AS Version
    FROM versions
   WHERE CURR_VER = 'N'                                           -- required?
GROUP BY NAMEJOB;
```

Or using `row_number()`

```
SELECT NAMEJOB, CREATION_DATE, VERSION
  FROM (SELECT v.*,
               ROW_NUMBER ()
                  OVER (PARTITION BY NAMEJOB ORDER BY VERSION DESC)
                  rn
          FROM versions v
         WHERE CURR_VER = 'N') t
 WHERE rn = 1;
```